# Find the average rate of change and instantaneous rate of change

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

The cost in dollars of producing $x$ units of a certain item is:
$C(x) = 5000 + 10 x + 0.05 x^2$.

Find the average rate of change from $C$ with respect to $x$ when the production level is changed from $x = 100$ to $x = 105$ and from $x = 100$ to $x = 101$.

Find also the instantaneous rate of change of $C$ with respect to $x$, when $x = 100$ (this is known as the marginal cost).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not a mathematica question

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are calling the "average rate of change" is computed by [`DifferenceQuotient`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DifferenceQuotient.html) in Mathematica. The "instantaneous rate of change" is just the derivative.

```
c[x_] := 5000 + 20 x + 5 x^2/100
```

Average rate of change when production changes from 100 to 105 units

```
DifferenceQuotient[c[x], {x, 105 - 100}] /. x -> 100 // N
```

> `30.25`

Average rate of change when production changes from 100 to 101 units

```
DifferenceQuotient[c[x], {x, 101 - 100}] /. x -> 100 // N
```

> `30.05`

Instantaneous rate of change at 100 units

```
c'[x] /. x -> 100 // N
```

> `30.`

This last can be written more concisely as

```
c'[100]
```

> `30`